# Is Inclusion–Exclusion Principle still valid if $\cap$ and $\cup$ are exchanged?

Tags: combinatorics

The principle for the case of three sets, states:
$$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$
I wonder whether there exists a similar formula, where $\cap$ and $\cup$ are exchanged; for example:
$$|A\cap B\cap C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cup B|-|A\cup C|-|B\cup C|+|A\cup B\cup C|$$
If yes, is there a way to find the cardinality of the intersection of n sets?

Comment: Consider only 2 set - what will give your last formula?

Comment: Yes I find that $|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|$, which is correct.

Comment: @Mark. Ok. Now you are ready for induction step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is such a duality. It works for $n$ sets, but I'll outline the three-set version. The general principle is the same. I'll assume that all sets are subsets
of a finite set $X$, and use $A^c$ for the complement of $A$ in $X$, etc.

Take your first identity, and
$$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$$
and replace each set by its complement:
$$|A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c|=|A^c|+|B^c|+|C^c|-|A^c\cap B^c|-|A^c\cap C^c|-|B^c\cap C^c|+|A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c|.$$
De Morgan's laws give
$$|(A\cap B\cap C)^c|=|A^c|+|B^c|+|C^c|-|(A\cup B)^c|-|(A\cup C)^c|-|(B\cup C)^c|+|(A\cup B\cup C)^c|.$$
But $|D^c|=|X|-|D|$ for all $D\subseteq X$. Applying this throughout gives
$$|X|-|A\cap B\cap C|=|X|-|A|-|B|-|C|+|A\cup B|+|A\cup C|+|B\cup C|-|A\cup B\cup C|.$$
From this
$$|A\cap B\cap C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cup B|-|A\cup C|-|B\cup C|+|A\cup B\cup C|$$
is immediate.